# incorrect null reference warning

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I've got a flow in which a code and more variables are checked if empty, sets an errormessage and returns if so. Yet still a warning is emitted on GetName that "code possible null reference argument". I can be sure that code is not null at that point. How does one usually avoid this?

```
if (IsNullOrEmpty(code) || IsNullOrEmpty(order))
    errorMessage = "missing data";

if (!IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)) return;

var dbd = await GetName(code); // warning here
```

Comment: Nullable analysis does not solve the halting problem. It checks one level of indirection, not more.

Comment: If you know code is not null, just disable the warning by writing `GetName(code!)`.

Comment: *Don't* disable the warning. Refactor the code so both other programmers and the compiler can tell why `code` is not null. Right now you expect the compiler to *indirectly* understand that `code` isn't null because some other variable is set at runtime. Why not use `return "missing data"` instead of this?

Comment: @pmf that should be the answer

Comment: because the real code has more checks, this is a reduced example

Answer (score 1):

C#'s null-state static analysis won't (yet) consider even local variables in which you stored null-states.

This simplified example of your code demonstrates that:

```cs
static void NonNullArg(string code) { }

string? code = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MayBeNull");

bool isNull = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code);

if (isNull)
{
    return;
}

NonNullArg(code);
```

> Warning   CS8604  Possible null reference argument for parameter 'code' in 'void NonNullArg(string code)'.

If you inline the check and omit the variable, the warning disappears:

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
{
    return;
}

NonNullArg(code);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if (IsNullOrEmpty(code) || IsNullOrEmpty(order))
{
    return;
}
else
{
    var dbd = await GetName(code); // no more warning here
}
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an explanation, and if you have a return in an if, you don't need an else block.

Comment: @CodeCaster He can read your answer for further explanation. Secondly I believe this is self explaining code.